# Register a Segue on a Parent View Controller to use on Child View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I am wondering if it is possible to register a Segue on a Parent View Controller to use within a Child View Controller.

Example: I have a custom `AlertViewController` and all of my main view controllers inherit from `BaseViewController`. I use this custom AlertViewController in most of these instead of the UIAlertView and I currently have to copy the AlertViewController and connect it to each subclass of BaseViewController in my storyboard.

Is there a way for me to register the segue to the AlertViewController on the BaseViewController class so that any subclass can successfully use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined a way to do what I was wanting here. I just need to manually perform the segue in my BaseViewController class in the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method.

Example:

In my BaseViewController

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier withSender:(NSObject *)sender {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MyCustomSegue"]) {
        MyNewViewController *MNVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNewViewController"];

        ...

        [self presentViewController:MNVC animated:YES completion:nil];

        return;
    }

    [super performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier withSender:sender];
}
```

In my ChildViewController

```
[self performSegueForIdentifier:@"MyCustomSegue" sender:nil];
```

With this approach I no longer have to copy the MyNewViewController storyboard object and connect it to each ChildViewController in my storyboard. I do have to create the MyNewViewController within my storyboard however and make sure it's storyboardID is whatever I call it within code.